# Create a folder in My Documents and save a workbook to that folder

Tags: excel, windows-7, excel-2007, vba

I created an Excel Add-In that is used on a workbook with imported data. I need to add code that will do the following:

- Check if folder exists C:\Users\\My Documents\ **Extract
  Files**\
- Create the folder if it does not exist
- Save the file into this folder with current date and time (Now) in the file name with an .xlsx  extension.

Example: C:\Users\jdoe\My Documents\Extract Files\Extract - 01-15-2016 15:15.xlsx

I have found this, but need to know how to get my criteria above into this code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

I do not know enough about VBA to create a folder if it does not exist (if you can do this with VBA). I have looked but could not find anything that was helpful. Asking for some guidance here. Thanks.

Comment: I just noticed that the full path is not in my OP. I need to add that different users will run this from their desktop and need to save this file in their respective My Documents folder. In my OP it should have said: C:\Users\username\My Documents\Extract Files\. Extract Files is the folder that I need to be created if it does not already exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    Sub Ex()
If InStr(LCase$(ActiveWorkbook.name), "extract") > 0 Then
    Exit Sub
Else
     Dim MyDir As String, fn As String
     MyDir = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments") & "\Extract Files" ' change this to valid path
     If Len(Dir(MyDir, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir MyDir
     fn = MyDir & "\Extract - " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy hh_mm")
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fn, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
End If
End Sub
```

we can not use `:` in the file name

Comment: Thanks. I was only thinking of the format for the time, not that it would be part of the file name. Good catch. But how do I get this to go into the users My documents (See my comment to the OP).

Comment: @IronMan,see edit . and if you want user data folder you can use `Environ("USERPROFILE")`.

Comment: The code provided above worked perfectly. But, for future reference, how do I incorporate your suggestion above (use Environ("USERPROFILE") into the macro? This is new to me.

Comment: @IronMan, You can use: `Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\My Documents\ Extract Files"`. but using  `WScript.Shell` like in the answer is better because it always give correct result , like my case my user data folder is in C: and My Documents folder is in D: , so  I can't use `Environ`

Comment: That is great info. Thanks for sharing. Our corporate setup is plain, so our My Documents is in the default location. This would work for us if needed.

Comment: if My Documents is in the default location then I think both cases will work.

Comment: I edited your answer. I found that, since this code is activated from a custom menu button that is used several times in our process, it was creating several versions of the workbook. I added some code to the beginning that prevents this from reoccurring. It checks to see if the active workbook has already been named.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim folder As String, myFileName As String
   folder = "C:\TestFolder\Extract Files"

   On Error Resume Next
      MkDir folder
   On Error GoTo 0

   myFileName = folder & "\" & "Extract - " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy hh mm") & ".xlsx"
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
End Sub
```

after changing the folder name.................if you get a warning, click on the <kbd>yes</kbd> button

The macro will create the folder if it does not exist.

Comment: Student Love the sub name...lol. But how do I get this into the users My documents? You and Fadi have both provided good answers and will work for me except for this one requirement. Thank you for assisting.